# set footer on the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html

I have different size of page in my website

How do I set the footer always on the bottom of the page?

Please notice that I need it on the bottom of the page and not on the bottom of the screen, so if I have short screen it will be at the bottom of it, and if I have long, scroll, page I'll see the footer only if I'll scroll down.

Thanks

```
<footer>
    <?PHP include "footer.php"; ?>
</footer>
```

css:

```
footer {
    background: #294a2d; 
    width:100%;
    height: 180px; 
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Is the footer child of the `body` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute;` on the footer and `min-height` on the body tag like this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2ArDD/8/)** <-- with little content
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2ArDD/10/)** <-- with a lot of content

HTML :

```
<div>... Content ...</div>
<footer>... Footer ...</footer>
```

CSS :

```
   html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
}
div {
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:gold;
}
```

Comment: if you have long page, with scrolling, the footer will appear in the bottom of the screen, but not at the bottom of th page...

Comment: @user3396295 Well you can see in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2ArDD/8/ that the footer sticks to the bottom although there is not enuogh content to push it down and in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2ArDD/10/ with enough content to make the scrollbar appear that the footer is pushed by the content.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```
footer {
position : absolute ;
bottom : 0 !important ;
background: #294a2d; 
width:100%;
height: 180px; 
color: #fff;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
html {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
   padding: 25px;
}


footer {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

`<footer>
 <h1>Footer Content</h1>
</footer>`

Answer (score 0):

I use ryan fait's sticky footer:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/